# java.lang.NullPointerException while using PeasyCam and Processing. PeasyCam says it cannot read "width" because <parameter2> is null

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing

I am using `IntelliJ idea`, `processing`, `peasy` and obviously `Java` to run everything. I'm trying to use PeasyCam in my `setting()` method and it keeps giving me this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "width" because "<parameter2>" is null
    at peasy.PeasyCam.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at peasy.PeasyCam.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.nod.planets.Main.settings(Main.java:14)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleSettings(PApplet.java:978)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10897)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10657)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10639)
    at com.nod.planets.Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

Honestly I'm completely new to peasy and processing and I'm stuck when it comes to debugging this.

Here's the code for reference:

```
package com.nod.planets;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import peasy.*;

public class Main extends PApplet
{
    PeasyCam cam;

    @Override
    public void settings()
    {
        size(600, 600, P3D);
        cam = new PeasyCam(this, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw()
    {
        background(0);
        fill(255);
        lights();
        //translate(width / 2, height / 2);

       float sphereRadius = 200;
       int sphereVertices = 100;
       for (int i = 0; i < sphereVertices; i++)
       {
           float longitude = map(i, 0, sphereVertices, -PI, PI);
           for (int j = 0; j < sphereVertices; j++)
           {
               float latitude = map(j, 0, sphereVertices, -HALF_PI, HALF_PI);
               float x = sphereRadius * sin(longitude) * cos(latitude);
               float y = sphereRadius * sin(longitude) * sin(latitude);
               float z = sphereRadius * cos(longitude);
               stroke(255);
               strokeWeight(2);
               point(x, y, z);
           }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PApplet.main("com.nod.planets.Main");
    }
}
```

If I get rid of initializing the PeasyCam and uncomment the `translate(width / 2, height / 2);` code then it works like a charm, but the minute I try this it gives that error... It's just this damn "easy" "PeasyCam" that's giving me the trouble. Also yes I am trying to make planets with perlin noise terrain in case you're wondering. Don't @ me on whether it'll work or not (idk tbh), just please help me in figuring out why it's giving me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be caused by the `PApplet` object not being fully initialized when the `settings` function is called.

Background information: the "main" constructor of the `PeasyCam` class uses a `PGraphics` object which is derived from the `PApplet` object. This `PGraphics` object might be null when `settings` is called, which would cause [the following line](https://github.com/jdf/peasycam/blob/master/src/peasy/PeasyCam.java#L136) in the `PeasyCam` constructor to fail:

```
viewport[2] = pg.width;
```

You can postpone the initialization of the camera to the `setup` function like this (thanks to [George Profenza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89766/george-profenza) for improving this answer):

```
@Override
public void settings()
{
    size(600, 600, P3D);
}

@Override
public void setup()
{
    cam = new PeasyCam(this, 200);
}

@Override
public void draw()
{
    background(0);
    // [...]
}
```